# Cannot implicity convert string into Model type

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework

I have a ViewModel

```
  public class SubjectOverviewViewModel
    {
        [DisplayName("Neptunkód")]
        public Subject NeptunId { get; set; }
        public SubjectContent TaFoAdatok { get; set; }
        public SubjectContent TaAdatok { get; set; }
        public SubjectContent TaOktatok { get; set; }
        public SubjectContent TaKurzusok { get; set; }
        public SubjectContent IrodalomLista { get; set; }
        public virtual SubjectContent SubjectContent { get; set; }

        public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    }
```

and a contoller:

```
irfwebpage20161013070934_dbEntities2 db = new irfwebpage20161013070934_dbEntities2(); //dbcontext class
            List<SubjectOverviewViewModel> list = new List<SubjectOverviewViewModel>(); // to hold list of Customer and order details
            var customerlist = (from x in db.Subject
                                join c in db.SubjectContent on x.NeptunId equals c.NeptunId
                                select new SubjectOverviewViewModel { NeptunId=c.NeptunId,
                                    TaAdatok=c.TaAdatok,
                                    TaFoAdatok=c.TaFoAdatok,
                                    IrodalomLista=c.IrodalomLista,
                                    TaKurzusok=c.TaKurzusok });
```

In the `select new SubjectOverviewViewModel` section i get the error that for example c.TaAdatok is string and it cannot implicitly convert it into model type. The First arguemnt NeptunID doesn't show any error although it is also a string type just like the others. Please help I'm stuck here. I looked at other threads on StackOverflow but those solutions I already implemented and didn't work.

```
public partial class SubjectContent
    {
        public string NeptunId { get; set; }
        public string TaFoAdatok { get; set; }
        public string TaAdatok { get; set; }
        public string TaOktatok { get; set; }
        public string TaKurzusok { get; set; }
        public string IrodalomLista { get; set; }

        public virtual Subject Subject { get; set; }
    }

 public partial class Subject
    {
        public string NeptunId { get; set; }
        public string Name { get; set; }

        public virtual Node Node { get; set; }
        public virtual SubjectContent SubjectContent { get; set; }
        public virtual SubjectRating SubjectRating { get; set; }

        public static implicit operator Subject(string v)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
    }
```

Subject and SubjectContent are created by database-first method of entity data modelling.

Comment: Well, not knowing what `SubjectContent` and `Subject` are, I'm sure they're not strings. I'm also sure that `NeptunId=c.NeptunId` throws an exception. Maybe you should describe what you're trying to achieve, how you expect to create `Subject/SubjectContent` objects from strings.

Comment: Szia Tamás! What is the type of the `SubjectOverviewViewModel.TaAdatok` property? Maybe it is something other than `string` and that's the cause of the problem.

Comment: Right - for example, show class `SubjectOverviewViewModel.TaAdatok`.

Comment: I am trying to create a details View which shows all the corresponding data of a subject according to a NeptunID. For example /Subjects/Details/NeptundID url will show the TaAdatok, IrodalomLista etc. of that subject

Comment: So why are all these properties typed `SubjectContent`? They should just be strings. But look at your classes: there are navigation properties `Subject.SubjectContent` and `SubjectContent.Subject`. You don't need the join. You can simply get all required `Subject` data through `SubjectContent.Subject` and project the strings and the `Subject` directly into a view model.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that here:

```
var customerlist = (from x in db.Subject
                            join c in db.SubjectContent on x.NeptunId equals c.NeptunId
                            select new SubjectOverviewViewModel { NeptunId=c.NeptunId,
                                TaAdatok=c.TaAdatok,
                                TaFoAdatok=c.TaFoAdatok,
                                IrodalomLista=c.IrodalomLista,
                                TaKurzusok=c.TaKurzusok });
```

`c.TaAdatok` is a `string` but `SubjectOverviewViewModel.TaAdatok` is of type `SubjectContent`.

I think the property types in your view model are wrong. Try this:

```
public class SubjectOverviewViewModel
{
    [DisplayName("Neptunkód")]
    public string NeptunId { get; set; }
    public string TaFoAdatok { get; set; }
    public string TaAdatok { get; set; }
    public string TaOktatok { get; set; }
    public string TaKurzusok { get; set; }
    public string IrodalomLista { get; set; }
}
```

You can also greatly simplify your query because, as @GertArnold saind in the comments, you already have a `SubjectContent` navigation property on `Subject`:

```
var customerlist = from s in db.Subject
                   let sc = s.SubjectContent
                   select new SubjectOverviewViewModel
                   {
                       NeptunId = sc.NeptunId,
                       TaAdatok = sc.TaAdatok,
                       TaFoAdatok = sc.TaFoAdatok,
                       IrodalomLista = sc.IrodalomLista,
                       TaKurzusok = sc.TaKurzusok
                   };
```

As a last remark, why do you call the variable `customerlist` even though it contains data about subjects?